# How to make Ajax.ActionLink send Http Post request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, post, razor

If I run the following code I got error message "*A public action method 'PostAction' was not found on controller...*". Fiddler shows GET request instead of POST is used. I tried to replace Html.BeginForm by Ajax.BeginForm, it did not help. So what do I do wrong? Thanks.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Ajax.ActionLink("ClickMe", "PostAction", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }) 
}

[HttpPost]
 public virtual ActionResult PostAction() { ... }
```

UPDATE, additional info: That's how MVC generates Html anchor:

```
<a onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, httpMethod: 'POST' });" href="/.../PostAction/">ClickMe</a>
```

Comment: Right, but it's not just hyperlink, MVC handles its click event and tries to run it in POST mode, at least that's how it suppose to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I just forgot to add references to MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js. As I added them, everything works fine. Sorry for the silly post

Comment: These are obsolete in MVC3 and MVC4. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8784998/210780