# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Ajax.BeginForm and html5

Tags: ajax, html, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

### The Setup:

I have updated an app from ASP.NET MVC 3 to ASP.NET MVC 4.

The app worked fine in MVC 3.  The only thing that isn't working in MVC 4 is Ajax.Begin form:  the form defaults to full page requests, instead of async AJAX requests.

Essentially, it is a wizard that I have written, but that is irrelevant.  Model.Step.ActionName correctly returns a string (see code below).

### The Code:

The code in the View is:

```
@{ 
    using (Ajax.BeginForm(Model.Step.ActionName, null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "wizardStep", OnBegin="isValid", LoadingElementId="PleaseWait", OnSuccess="SetFocusOnForm" }, 
        new {@name="wizardForm", @id="wizardForm" } ))
{

//form contents

}
}
```

### The Rendering:

I note that Ajax.BeginForm in MVC 4 uses HTML 5.  I show the difference between how MVC 3 and MVC 4 render the form below:

**MVC 3:**

```
<form action="/Solicitors/Company/New/YourDetails" id="wizardForm" method="post" name="wizardForm" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));" onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, loadingElementId: 'PleaseWait', updateTargetId: 'wizardStep', onBegin: Function.createDelegate(this, isValid), onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, SetFocusOnForm) });">

// form contents

</form>
```

**MVC 4:**

```
<form action="/Solicitors/Company/New/LoginDetails" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="isValid" data-ajax-loading="#PleaseWait" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="SetFocusOnForm" data-ajax-update="#wizardStep" id="wizardForm" method="post" name="wizardForm" novalidate="novalidate">

// form contents

</form>
```

I have no idea if this is correct, but assume it is.

### The Problem:

The problem, however, is that Ajax isn't used, just full page refreshes.  So sumat is wrong...

### The Question:

The question is:  What is wrong?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I have solved this.

In the MVC 3 app, I had commented out the following in the web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0" />
    <!--<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />-->
  </appSettings>
```

This explains why asp.net mvc 3 was not rendering html 5.

In the new mvc 4 app, the default setting has `ClientValidationEnbled=true` and `UnobstrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=true`, as follows:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    ...
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

So my app needed the following javascript files to be included:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it needed the microsoft*.js files throwing away, ie:

```
@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
```

I figured this out after reading @Darin Dimitrov's reply to the following question:

[Are MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcValidation.js obsolete as of ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8782697/271087)

Many thanks to Darin.  The answer is worth reading, to enlighten yourself as to the meaning of the two appSettings I had disabled.