# ajax.action link is not showing alert on success

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am working on asp.net MVC 2 application. I have ajax.action link but it is not working. I have this code in my view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function success(result) {
           alert(result);
           // TODO: do something with the object
       }
   </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%: Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    new { Id = 55 }, 
    new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "success" })
%>
</asp:Content>
```

and this is controller code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
      ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

      return View();
 }



 public JsonResult Delete(Int32 Id) {

     return Json("Record deleted!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

But when I click the link, It shows Record deleted! in browser instead of showing as alert. Am I missing some file(s) ?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/15448070/ajax-actionlink-not-showing-alert-onsuccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to include the `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` scripts to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>"></script>
```

In ASP.NET MVC 3 and later those files are [`obsolete and replaced`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8784998/29407) by the jQuery unobtrusive scripts.

Now that you have sent me your sample project by mail it is clear what the problem is. You have defined your success javascript function inside the `<title>` tag of your page which obviously cannot work.

So inside your MasterPage you should define a special placeholder for your scripts (notice also how I have fixed your hardcoded links to the CSS file with a url helper):

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Scripts" runat="server" />
</head>
```

that you could override in your view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Scripts" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function success() {
           alert('success');
           // TODO: do something with the object
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%= Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Delete", 
        "Delete", 
        new { id = 55 }, 
        new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "success" }
    ) %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: @ added this but still same issue

Comment: Are you sure that this is an ASP.NET MVC 2 application and not ASP.NET MVC 3? Also take a look at your browser console to see if there might be some js errors.

Comment: Yes, I am using asp.net MVC 2

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also where did you include those scripts?

Comment: Yes I included the scripts and no errors in console. When I click the link an error appears but disappears so fast that I cant note it and then ajax is displayed.

Comment: Is there a way to send this as attachment with post ?

Comment: No, there isn't. But you could send me the project by email so that I can take a look at what might be wrong.

Comment: what is the email address ?>

Comment: `darin.dimitrov [AT] gmail [DOT] com`

Comment: Alright, got it. You have placed your success script in the title of your webpage which is incorrect. Move it to a specific section. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As always your answer helped me a lot. Thank you and SO