# alternate to MicrosoftAjax in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

but following library MicrosoftAjax and  MicrosoftMvcAjax is obsolete and and size is also additional is there any alternative..

i heard about unobtrusive ajax but i don't know how to use it..

my form is like

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("getConversionRate", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Result", OnSuccess = "onSuccess", OnBegin = "onBegin", OnComplete = "onComplete" }))
```

Comment: Probably the answer to this question is helpful: [Are MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js \[...\] obsolete as of ASP.NET MVC 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8782697/1960455)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set scripts src like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")"></script>
```

Secondly include theses files to make ajax forms work in mvc:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: is this compulsary

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")"></script>

Comment: i don't think so the script files i told you will do the job for you, i never used MicrosoftAjax.js file

Comment: just include the four files i mentioned and make sure they exist in the Scripts folder, it will work

Comment: ok thanks ehsan... i think validate.js is  not cumpulsary just for ajex

Comment: i another problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810453/conversion-web-form-to-razor-without-any-error