# conversion web form to razor without any error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am trying to convert to razor but showing an error

```
<%
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
    options.HttpMethod = "POST";
%>
```

---

```
@AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
    options.HttpMethod = "POST";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@{ 
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
    options.HttpMethod = "POST";
}
```